# if condition question in Magento for email template

Tags: magento2, template, payment

I need help to verify my if statement, I am not sure in Magento of using `"$block->escapeHtml($label)"` in if condition is correct or not

does my if statement correct for only showing "Card Number" & "Card Type" info?

thanks!

```
<?php if ($block->escapeHtml($label) == 'Card Number') || ( $block->escapeHtml($label) == 'Card Type') {?>
```

/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Block\Info $block
 * @see \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
 */
$specificInfo = $block->getSpecificInformation();
$title = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle());
?>
<dl class="payment-method">
    <dt class="title"><?= /* @noEscape */ $title ?></dt>
<?php if ($specificInfo) : ?>
    <dd class="content">
        <table class="data table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @noEscape */ $title ?></caption>
            <?php foreach ($specificInfo as $label => $value) : ?>
                <?php if ($block->escapeHtml($label) == 'Card Number') || ( $block->escapeHtml($label) == 'Card Type') {?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($label) ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ nl2br($block->escapeHtml(implode("\n", $block->getValueAsArray($value, true)))) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </dd>
<?php endif;?>
</dl>
<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Comment: <?php if ($label == 'Card Number') ||  $label == 'Card Type') {?> try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php if($block->escapeHtml($label) == 'Card Number' || $block->escapeHtml($label) == 'Card Type') {?>
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for pointing out my careless mistake. but inside the condition, I should use "$block->escapeHtml($label)" or just "$label" ?

Comment: You can use escapehtml. If answer help then upvote and mark as solution, so it will help others in community.